# Cannot boot windows from usb, but linux works

Tags: bootable-media

I seek for technical understanding. I was able to solve my issue using a DVD, but would like to understand it.

I have an old laptop here (Medion Akoya E7212, to be precise). I tried getting Windows 10 and Windows 7 booted off an usb-stick, but both failed. I tried using https://www.ventoy.net/ and a different tool that, opposed to Ventoy, creates a USB-Stick with just one system.

I already used this same method / USB-Stick successfully on a different laptop. I also used it on the Medion laptop with Linux systems and it booted just fine.

Just, for some reason, using the Medion laptop with Windows 10, it starts booting from the stick, but then gets stuck with a black screen and just a white underscore blinking in the top left of the screen. (I have not left it on for hours, but while the DVD went on from that state immediately the USB stayed there for 10 Minutes).

If you have some insight on what might cause that I am happy to know.

Please DO NOT discuss my choice of OS and stay to the topic of the question. There are specific and very valid reasons why I do what I do. I exclusively look for knowledge on what may cause this behaviour!

Comment: Have you ensured that your boot media is for Legacy, not EFI?

Comment: With only 4 GB in the OEM configuration, you might get better performance from Linux than resource-intensive Windows, anyway.

Comment: This ^^^ and Windows 7 shouldn't be used, peridod. Re: any **supported** Windows version yes, Ventoy works, I've personally tested multiple times (not in Legacy mode though). That said, Microsoft has an official tool that's triggered when downloading the installation ISO (from a Windows PC). That is the ONE that should be used.

Comment: @harrymc I was not aware that there are boot mediums that are only for Bios or EFI. That might indeed be the reason.

@ the two others:
I added a disclaimer to my original post for you.

Comment: @harrymc Can a boot medium be for both Legacy and EFI at the same time? I am asking because Ventoy is booting on all systems for me.